# Can no longer long in after trying to apply updates

Tags: desktop

Running Elementary on an HP ProBoob x360 e11 - has been great.

Went to apply updates this morning (around 3.4GB).

The updater app crashed/closed. I tried to reboot the machine.

Now I can't log back in when the login pages show up after reboot.

I can log in when going to alt+ctrl+F1

Any ideas?

thanks
Sam

Answer (score 1):

ok I fixed this by going into the CLI and fixing apt as when I tried to run the update it said the previous update attempt had been interrupted so needed a manual command to resolve.

Comment: Can you please mark the question answered?